# Need to interpolate scattered lat lon temperature data and plot

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a N x 3 dataset at a particular time. These are scatter data and their spacing are unequal.

From what I have read so far, it seems like imagesc(), meshgrid(), scatteredInterpolant (although i heard this is problematic for geographic interpolation) are the functions that are needed. I need to plot the map in decimal degrees. Finally, maps at various times are created and animated across time.

How could I perform this in MATLAB?

Comment: *I need to plot the map in decimal degrees* - do you mean that you want the data to be interpolated to 0.1 degrees spacing?

Comment: yes I guess that should be fine, or as a user specified variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So close! You can show the map with [`geoshow.`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/geoshow.html) Two typos in your code also had to be fixed:

```
% some sample data, located in europe
data = [randi([-10 30],10,1) randi([30 50],10,1) rand(10,1)];

lat = data(:,1);
lon = data(:,2);
temp = data(:,3); % : not ;
lon0 = min(lon) ; lon1 = max(lon) ;
lat0 = min(lat) ; lat1 = max(lat) ; 
N = 100 ;
x = linspace(lon0,lon1,N) ;
y = linspace(lat0,lat1,N) ; % lat0, not lon1
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y) ;
F = scatteredInterpolant(lon,lat,temp) ;
Z = F(X,Y) ;

worldmap('World') 
load coastlines    
plotm(coastlat,coastlon)
geoshow(X,Y,Z,'DisplayType', 'texturemap') % options give it a nice colormap for temperature - but you might want to change them to something more of your taste
```

Now, to control the interpolation resolution, just adjust the number of points:

```
spacing = 0.1;
x = linspace(lon0,lon1-mod(abs(lon0-lon1),spacing), floor(abs(lon0-lon1)/spacing)+1) ;
y = linspace(lat0,lat1-mod(abs(lat0-lat1),spacing), floor(abs(lat0-lat1)/spacing)+1) ;
```

If you want to make a movie, just put the whole thing in a loop. At the end of the loop save each frame with:

```
M(k) = getframe;
```

Then you can play the movie with [`movie(M,PlayMovieNTimes,FramesPerSecond)`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html), or save it to your drive with [`videowriter`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html) - see the examples there.